# for loop iterable not overwriting original

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to find all fullstops in a body of text and create a whitespace in from of them. I am only allowed to use for loops or I would use regular expression. I can't understand why the following for-loop does not replace the original `letter` with my new assignment. My code is as follows:

```
text = 'I have a ruler and bought for 25 gpb.'

text_split = text.split()

for word in text_split:
    for letter in word:
        if letter == '.':
            letter = ' .'
```

If anyone could help then it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're allowed to use `str.replace()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letter = ' .'` just rebinds the name `letter` to a different string. The original object bound to `letter` is unchanged (and can't be changed even in theory; `str` is an immutable type). A similar problem prevents changing the original `str` in `text_split` bound to `word` on each loop.

For this specific case, you just want:

```
text_split = [word.replace('.', ' .') for word in text_split]
```

or the slightly longer spelled out version (that modifies `text_split` in place instead of replacing it with a new `list` of modified `str`):

```
for i, word in enumerate(text_split):
    text_split[i] = word.replace('.', ' .')
```

Comment: Why not do the replace on the whole string at once?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile: Yeah, that would be the more reasonable solution. Missed forest for the trees there.